# Navigation Controller not being displayed when created programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios13

I just updated to iOS 13/Xcode 11 and I'm trying to embed my UIViewController inside a UINavigationController as I have done in the past. The ViewController is displayed but my NavigationController is not. Below is what I have inside the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method inside AppDelegate.

```
    window = UIWindow()

    let vc = ViewController()
    let navController : UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
    navController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor : UIColor.black]

    window?.rootViewController = navController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

EDIT:
I found my error, I was trying to create the VC programmatically but I had the storyboard as the "initial view controller". This completely ignored my code in appdelegate even though I cleared the "Main Interface" field in my project's General settings.

I also want to note that my code shouldn't have been in appdelegate, instead, it should have been inside SceneDelegate. More info on that over here: https://medium.com/@ZkHaider/apples-new-uiscene-api-a-programmatic-approach-52d05e382cf2

Comment: Did you try to set title for navigationBar?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try using the identifier of the navigation controller

```
    let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "--navigation controller identifier--") as! --class name--
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
```